# How non-tensioned wheel scales?

Tags: classical-mechanics, stress-strain

As I was reading "Bicycle The history" by Herlihy I noticed something confusing.

Book says that typical weight of [draisine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_bicycle#1817_to_1819:_the_draisine_or_velocipede) was forty to fifty pounds. But typical weight of bicycle with wooden wheels some 50 years later was 70 pounds(and use of tensioned spokes immediately dropped 25 pound off the bicycle weight).

But there are only some minor differences between draisines and early bicycles - bigger wheels, pedals and that's about all, and technology obviously could only improve in those 50 years.

I thought about it and I feel that the reason of this is wooden wheel scales very bad.

In order to avoid buckling of spokes, as you increase diameter of the wheel but keep load the same, you need to increase spokes crossection as square of the wheel diameter, and lenght of spokes will increase as well. So **I think there is cubic dependency**, and 1.5 times bigger wheel for same load would weight about 3 times bigger. That could explain the difference in weight.

But I am not sure how rim weight would scale. So the question is - if you increase diameter of wheel and keep designed load the same, how the weight of the wheel changes, according to mechanics of materials?

Comment: Note that there is [bicycles.se] that might be more appropriate for this question.

Comment: It's not just the size of the wheel: a bicycle has a wheel which is *driven*: it needs to withstand someone standing on the pedals without collapsing, and transfer torque to the rim.  I don't see why wooden wheels should not work with the spokes in overall tension as wire wheels do so buckling may not be a problem.  Note that the way wire wheels work is fairly non-intuitive.

Comment: @tfb can please you give me a couple pointers - where can I read about wire wheels?

Comment: The Bicycle Wheel by Jobst Brandt looks interesting.

Comment: @vashu: Jobst Brandt's book is the one I have read.  As far as I know he was the person who sorted out how bicycle wheels actually work, which I think he did by numerically modelling them.  However I can't believe there are not other works on the subject as wire wheels were very widely used in high-performance cars until, I suppose, aluminium wheels took over.  Car wheels may work differently than bicycle wheels though: the rim is more rigid for instance.